# Why is Spring-Data-JPA Async not working?

Tags: asynchronous, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

I am trying to create a non-blocking rest service with Spring Boot and Spring data JPA.

How to do Async save of an entity with Spring Data JPA @Async support. Below code is not working for me although other selects seem to be working on the same entity.

I am trying to do this within a JPA Repository. Here is full repository : except for save.  These methods are working fine and I could test them

```
public interface LoanRepository extends JpaRepository<Loan,Long> {

@Query("select distinct loan from Loan loan left join fetch loan.collaterals left join fetch loan.partys")
@Async
CompletableFuture<List<Loan>> findAllWithEagerRelationships();

@Query("select loan from Loan loan left join fetch loan.collaterals left join fetch loan.partys where loan.id =:id")
@Async
CompletableFuture<Loan> findOneWithEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);

@Async
void delete(Long id);
```

}

However, when I try to add the below save method :

```
    @Async
    <S extends CompletableFuture<Loan>> S save(Loan loan);
```

I get an obvious compilation error which says `"The method save(Loan) is ambiguous for the type LoanRepository"`

I tried changing it to :

```
    @Async
    <S extends CompletableFuture<Loan>> S save(S loan);
```

But I get an exception at startup `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null` which is due to :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.potentiallyUnwrapReturnTypeFor(QueryMethod.java:244)
```

The Spring Data JPA Documentation on Async support is not clear on Save part of it.  [Spring Data JPA Async Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue myself and after trying some variations this seems to work:

```java
@Async
@Override
<S extends Loan> CompletableFuture<S> save(S loan);
```

Comment: Does this actually run things asynchronously though? I thought `@Async` would only work if it returns `Future` or `void`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to just return `CompletableFuture` instead? Something like this (untested):

```java
@Async
<S extends Loan> CompletableFuture<S> save(S loan);
```

You can't extend from `JpaRepository` though, because this will clash from the one it inherited from `CrudRepository`. Extend from `Repository` instead and copy whatever method you need from `CrudRepository`, `PagingAndSortingRepository`, or `JpaRepository`

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: maybe saving requires a transaction, while queries not. Try with `@Transactional`...